# How to create a string in LLVM IR

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I am writing a pass to do some modifications to IR and need to create a function call which requires a string as parameter. I created string using:

```
string str = fn.getName();  // Name of a function is what I need to pass as argument
Value * v = builder.CreateGlobalString(StringRef(str), "func_name");
```

But this creates a string with type:

```
[4 x i8]*
```

When I print the required argument type for the function, I get:

```
%"class.std::__cxx11::basic_string"*
```

How can I create a string with `%"class.std::__cxx11::basic_string"*` type?

Comment: Uh... std::string is a c++ class. You create an instance of a c++ class by compiling the right c++... I think I may not understand the question.

Comment: What kind of string are we expecting and what target language do you work against? I would guess that you work with C++. One possible solution would be to write a function with the same signature taking a C-string that wraps the other function taking a C++ string. Then you can pass the [4 x i8]* to the wrapper function which calls the C++ function. I assume that you are not compiling IR together now and that you will have the function with the C signature in some sort of runtime library

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, when you use 'CreateGlobalString' from 'IRBuilder', you are creating 'GlobalVariable' with [N x i8]* initializer (an array of N elements of type i8 - a char type).

The std::string is something more complex for LLVM IR. For instance, the following line of code in your program

```
std::string std;
```

will be represented in IR by many lines, among them are lines to define types

```
%"class.std::__cxx11::basic_string" = type { %"struct.std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::_Alloc_hider", i64, %union.anon }
%"struct.std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::_Alloc_hider" = type { i8* }
%union.anon = type { i64, [8 x i8] }
```

directly in the function, when you have `std::string` on stack, you will find at least following lines to allocate object

```
  %2 = alloca %"class.std::__cxx11::basic_string", align 8
```

to call default ctor

```
call void @_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1Ev(%"class.std::__cxx11::basic_string"* noundef nonnull align 8 dereferenceable(32) %2) #2
```

and finally to call dtor

```
call void @_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEED1Ev(%"class.std::__cxx11::basic_string"* noundef nonnull align 8 dereferenceable(32) %2) #2
```

and also you will find declarations of these functions (ctor and dtor)

```
declare void @_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1Ev(%"class.std::__cxx11::basic_string"* noundef nonnull align 8 dereferenceable(32)) unnamed_addr #1
declare void @_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEED1Ev(%"class.std::__cxx11::basic_string"* noundef nonnull align 8 dereferenceable(32)) unnamed_addr #1
```

So likely the easiest solution here is to make a wrapper function as mentioned above.